# Perl - Error when trying to access two-digit number in array within foreach-loop

Tags: perl, foreach

I just started learning Perl and stumbled across an error that I couldnt solve by googling or reading the book I'm learning with.

My code looks like this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (1, 2, 10);

foreach my $i (@array) {
    print $array[$i-1];
}
```

This works well if I have an array consisting only of single-digit numbers. As soon as the foreach-loop reaches a double-digit number (10 in this case), I get a warning saying *"Use of uninitialized value in ..."* and the loop stops. The same happens if I try to do anything with the numbers (addition etc.), it works well with single-digits, but stops at double-digits.

I'm now having trouble understanding what's happening here - I guess it has anything to do with the way that Perl stores the elements of the array, but I can't find anything and don't really know what to search for.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this doesn't do what you think it does.

```
my @array = (1, 2, 10);
foreach my $i (@array) {
    print $array[$i-1];
}
```

`$i` is not an index like 0, 1, 2, 3... Instead `$i` is each element of `@array`: 1, 2, 10. So `$array[$i-1]` is `$array[0]`, `$array[1]`, `$array[9]`. `@array` has no ninth element.

If you want to loop through each *index* of `@array`, loop like this:

```
for my $idx (0..$#array) {
    # 0, 1, 2
    print "$idx\n";
}
```

If you want to loop through each *element* of `@array`, loop like this:

```
for my $element (@array) {
    # 1, 2, 10
    print "$element\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! My mistake was the wrong use of the foreach-loop - I'll have another look into this. Too bad I cant select more than one answer as the correct one.

Comment: or `for my $idx (keys @array)`

Answer (score 2):

While you work with a book I'd like to suggest to also use the excellent [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/). Here are some examples in the context of an answer.  While at it I'll also suggest a few other niceties.

From [Foreach loops (perlsyn page)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops)

> The foreach loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the scalar variable VAR to be each element of the list in turn.

Thus it picks each *element* from an array

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @words = qw(one two three);

foreach my $word (@words) {
    say $word;
}
```

The [say](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) builtin is like `print` but adds the newline, see [feature pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html). The [`qw` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) builds a list of "words" (separated by spaces) which  is assigned to array `@words`. It is often very convienent.

If you only want to print an array, the [statement modifiers (perlsyn)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) are handy

```
say for @array;
```

This also makes use of the [`$_` variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables), which is a default for many things in Perl. So the above is same as `say $_ for @array`.

If you'd rather iterate over array *indices* that can be done nicely using the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)

```
foreach my $index (0 .. $#array) {
    say "$array[$index] at index $index";
}
```

where `$#array` is a bit special notation for the subscript (index) of the last element of `@array`. Find it under [Scalar values in perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values). When range is used in `foreach` loops there is *no* temporary array built, so it is memory efficient. While it can also be used to make an array, `my @nums = 1..10;`

---

The code in the question iterates over elements but then uses them to index into the array.  So it does `print $array[ $element ]`. This runs without trouble only accidentally when the elements happen to be numbers, and which happen to be valid indices for that particular array.

Comment: Note that `foreach my $index (0 .. $#array)` does not build a list, that could consume a lot of memory if `@array` is large. Instead it iterates through each value of that range, so it's quite memory efficient. I believe only `foreach` has this optimization of the range operator; `@a = (1..5)` still builds a list.

Comment: @Schwern Ah!  Nice, didn't know that. Edited, thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

In the Perl `foreach` you could access each element directly from the iteration variable, in your case it's `$i`.

Try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (1, 2, 10);

foreach my $i (@array) {
    print $i."\n";
}
```

Note the `."\n"` in the print function call. It's not needed, I've added that just to beautify the output.

Answer (score 1):

Both previous answers are good. I'll just add another slight variation to the mix.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (6, 1, 2, 10);
my $numelements = @array;

for (my $i=0; $i < $numelements; $i++) {
    print "$array[$i]\n";
}
```

Comment: While this will work, the 3 arg for loop is typically avoided in Perl. It's slower, harder to read, and invites bugs. Only use it if iterating over an array or range doesn't work. `$num_elements` is unnecessary, `$i < @array` is more straightforward.

Comment: Merely meant to show another way to skin the cat. At the same time, an example of how to get the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to mention the `each` function. You might now think that you have to choose between iterating over the index of the array and the values of the array:

**Iterating over the index:**

```
foreach my $index (0 .. $#array) {
    print "$index\n"; # 0, 1, 2
}
```

**Iterating over the values:**

```
foreach my $value (@array) {
    print "$value\n"; # 1, 2, 10
}
```

But you can have **both at the same time** if you have at least Perl 5.12. Use the [each](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) function:

```
while (my ($index, $value) = each @array) {
    print "index=$index, value=$value\n";
}
```

Output:

```
index=0, value=1
index=1, value=2
index=2, value=10
```

This can be useful if you want to iterate over an array and want to examine the previous or next element, for example.